# ELF-Binary compiled by gcc: What happens from entry point to main?

Tags: assembly, x86, elf

I get the entry point with readelf -h:

> Entry point address:               0x8048400

Debugging with gdb and Intel syntax:

```
(gdb) x/13i 0x8048400
0x8048400 <_start>: xor    ebp,ebp
0x8048402 <_start+2>:   pop    esi
0x8048403 <_start+3>:   mov    ecx,esp
0x8048405 <_start+5>:   and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x8048408 <_start+8>:   push   eax
0x8048409 <_start+9>:   push   esp
0x804840a <_start+10>:  push   edx
0x804840b <_start+11>:  push   0x8048590
0x8048410 <_start+16>:  push   0x8048520
0x8048415 <_start+21>:  push   ecx
0x8048416 <_start+22>:  push   esi
0x8048417 <_start+23>:  push   0x80484b4
0x804841c <_start+28>:  call   0x80483e0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
```

0x80484b4, the address of my main function, is pushed on the stack.

```
(gdb) x/1i 0x80483e0
0x80483e0 <__libc_start_main@plt>:  jmp    DWORD PTR ds:0x8049800
```

What is happening here? When I jump to 0x8049800 I get the following result:

```
(gdb) x/9i 0x8049800
0x8049800 <__libc_start_main@got.plt>:  out    0x83,al
0x8049802 <__libc_start_main@got.plt+2>:    add    al,0x8
0x8049804 <sub@got.plt>:    test   BYTE PTR [ebx+0x804],0x0
0x804980b <data_start+3>:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
0x804980d:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
0x804980f:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
0x8049811 <dtor_idx.5525+1>:    add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
0x8049813 <dtor_idx.5525+3>:    .byte 0x0
0x8049814:  Cannot access memory at address 0x8049814
```

I don't know how process continues. Can you help me?

Comment: Here's late at night so I haven't much time but this might help you a little: http://www.technovelty.org/linux/pltgot.html

Comment: good source: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice blog article about the topic: https://web.archive.org/web/20130325140610/http://bharathi.posterous.com/bash-prompt-to-main-call

Short answer: __libc_start_main() is a libc function, which calls the main function (and does a lot of other things). The address will be linked at startup (see BlackBears [link](http://www.technovelty.org/linux/pltgot.html)), that's why following the steps from the program entry to the main function by static debugging isn't possible.

But you can figure out the address of the main function through the push before __libc_start_main is called.

> 0x8048417 <_start+23>:  push   0x80484b4

@BlackBear: Thank you for the link!

Comment: The "bash prompt to main call" page is no longer available.

Comment: @AdamEvans Sorry for the late response. However, the blog article still exists in the Wayback Archive. I updated the link.